# Lua: How do I have it change a variable into a number in an equation?

Tags: lua

So I'm just getting into lua and wanted to make a program to do some calculations for me. Right now I have a series of elements followed by a number e.g. 
H = 1
He = 4
ect...
Then later in the script I want to be able to call the letter and have it work as a number. This is what I have.

```
    print ("Element 1")
    e1 = io.read()
    print ("Enter Subscript")
    sub1 = io.read("*n")
    e1s = e1 * sub1
    print (e1s)
```

In this I want the user to be able to input something like H, have it be seen as 1. Then the user can input the subscript and the 1 (from H) is multiplied by the number entered as subscript and then printed out for the user. Sorry if this didn't make much sense but any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the elements in a table and look them up when you need them:

```
elements = {H = 1, He = 4}
print("Element 1")
e1 = elements[io.read()]
print("Enter Subscript")
sub1 = io.read("*n")
e1s = e1 * sub1
print(e1s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If what your trying to do is print "H" as "HHH" provided the user provided 3, you can just use a loop to concatenate a string with all three, then just print that.

Comment: And not use [string.rep()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.rep) ?